# Tab completion for "git checkout" conflicting with "git cherry-pick"

Tags: git

I use `git checkout` all the time to change branches. It is very rare for me to use `git cherry-pick` and when I do it is usually from the gitk tool so I can see the commits visually.

When I start typing my muscle memory types `git ch` then I press TAB.

Sadly this gives me the following output:

> $ git ch
>   checkout      cherry        cherry-pick

I want git to ignore the fact that there is a command called `cherry-pick` and complete with `checkout`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant ignore it since its the default behaviour.

What you can do is one of the following:

define an alias named  `ch` so you will have to print only `git ch`

```
# defins a global shorcut for git checkout
git config --global alias.ch checkout

# checkout anything...
git ch master
```

Now you don't have to use the <kbd>tab</kbd> to complete the command.
You can also name it in any other name you wish if you don't want it to be `ch`

```
# for example name it foo:
git config --global alias.foo checkout

git foo master
```

To learn how to setup aliases and shortcuts for git commands:
https://githowto.com/aliases